# SQL date formatting

Tags: sql, date, formatting

I have a datetime column in my table. How to I display only the time?

Say, the value in the column is **2013-03-25 08:40:00.000**. How do I display the value **08:40** alone?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What database server software?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

`select Convert(varchar, getdate(), 8)`

OR

```
select SUBSTRING(Convert(varchar, GETDATE(), 8), 1, 5)
```

If you want only `hh:mm`

For more date formatting in SQL server [see this](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server:

Since you don't want to show only time in `hh:mm` format you can use this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), GETDATE(), 8)
```

For more information see [CAST and CONVERT (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms187928.aspx)

For MySQL:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), '%k:%i')
```